# ValueError: Shapes (None,) and (None, 1) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, keras-metrics

I have the following model :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(5,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(30, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(loss=['mean_absolute_error'], optimizer='adam',
metrics=[metrics.MeanAbsoluteError(), metrics.MeanRelativeError(normalizer=[1])])
```

My training/testing sets have the following shape :

```
x_train.shape
(114589, 5)

y_train.shape
(114589, 1)

x_test.shape
(49110, 5)

y_test.shape
(49110, 1)
```

I'm getting this error

```
ValueError: Shapes (None,) and (None, 1) are incompatible
```

This error has occurred after I added a new metric to my model [tf.keras.metrics.MeanRelativeError](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.6/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/MeanRelativeError).
What is causing this please? and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please provide the shape of your training data and testing data.

Comment: @ki-ljl I just did =)

Comment: try: `y_train = y_train.reshape(-1)`.

Comment: @M.Innat The error persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug to me, or at least this behavior is not well documented. The problem occurs because `y_pred` is squeezed internally (for some reason). As a workaround you can use a custom metric with the same [logic](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.8.0/keras/metrics.py#L653) as used for `MeanRelativeError`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def _mean_relative_error(normalizer):
  def mean_relative_error(y_pred, y_true):
    return tf.math.divide_no_nan(tf.abs(y_true - y_pred), normalizer)
  return mean_relative_error

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(5,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError(), _mean_relative_error(normalizer=[1])])
model.fit(tf.random.normal((10, 5)), tf.random.normal((10, 1)), epochs=2, batch_size=3)
```

```
Epoch 1/2
4/4 [==============================] - 1s 7ms/step - loss: 0.7566 - mean_absolute_error: 0.7209 - mean_relative_error: 0.7209
Epoch 2/2
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6665 - mean_absolute_error: 0.6625 - mean_relative_error: 0.6625
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f04dcfa4390>
```

You can experiment a bit with the `normalizer` parameter, since the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/MeanRelativeError) point out that `normalizer` should have the same shape as `y_pred`.

Comment: yes it did, thank you. However it gives the same results as MAE.

Comment: Yes since you you are using normalizer=[1]..have you tried changing the values? @mira